# Why does Z-Fighting occur for meshes sitting flush with each other, but not for meshes simply clipping into another mesh?

Tags: artifacts

I was about to experiment with a boolean modifier when I noticed this strange thing in my scene:

[image]

I understand why there is Z-fighting on  the two cubes on the top of the screen ( the blue and mint colored ones ). Their faces overlap and Blender can't quite decide which face to render.

But in the case of the two cubes intersecting the bigger blue cuboid on the the bottom, no Z-fighting occurs. Surely at the edge where the small cubes intersect with the cuboid, Blender would have trouble figuring which face's pixel at that point to shade right?

Yet the area seems Z-fighting free and looks relatively clean. What exactly in Blender is allowing for intersection of non-coplanar faces to render properly, even when there should logically be some issues rendering regions on and near the edges where the meshes intersect due to Z-fighting?

Comment: Because the faces can intersect each other and still each point in the face is either in the front or in the back of the other. Of course in the precise line of the intersection there would be points in both planes, but that is negligible. For each pixel in the image, there is only one face that is being rendered 'on top'. The same can't be said when two faces are coplanar.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati So essentially only for a few very few pixels do the edges overlap where the top cubes intersect with the bottom cuboid such that we get artifacting but because it's so tiny we don't see any visible artifacting?

Comment: I'm not sure. But I don't think there is any artifacting because for each pixel the software can determine that it's one face and not the other. The 'error' margin would be so small that it's much smaller than a pixel.